# Ошибка в WCF. System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException

Tags: c#, .net, windows-service, wcf

Здравствуйте!
Помогите разобраться. 
Ситуация следующая. Есть служба WCF собранный в WinService, с привязкой net.tcp. Служба не запускается, падает с ошибкой:

System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: В конечной IP-точке 0.0.0.0:8735 уже имеется прослушиватель. Это может быть вызвано тем, что другое приложение уже прослушивает эту конечную точку либо на узле служб имеется несколько конечных точек служб с одной и той же конечной IP-точкой, но с несовместимыми конфигурациями привязки. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Обычно разрешается только одно использование адреса сокета (протокол/сетевой адрес/порт)

Если меняю порт конечных точек на разный то все норм. На другой машине с одинаковыми портами работает, на моей (Windows 8) нет.

Config сервиса:

```
  <service name="">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8735/" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding1"  contract="">
    </endpoint>

    <!-- Metadata Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8735/"
                   binding="mexTcpBinding"
                   contract=""/>
  </service>

<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="Binding1"
             closeTimeout="00:01:00"
             openTimeout="00:01:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
             sendTimeout="00:01:00"
             transactionFlow="false"
             transferMode="Buffered"
             transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
             hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
             listenBacklog="10"
             maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
             maxBufferSize="65536"
             maxConnections="10"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
                    maxStringContentLength="8192"
                    maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true"
                       inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                       enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
      </security>
    </binding>
```

Нужные службы включены:

Адаптер прослушивателя Net.Tcp

Служба общего доступа к портам Net.Tcp

Спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Ну, из ошибки же ясно, что **на данном IP адресе и порту уже есть слушатель**. То есть либо ты второй раз запускаешь свою прогу (а первый экземпляр при этом уже работает), либо имеется какая то программа, слушающая на этом IP и порту.